# Rails 5.2 Callback for Active Storage Blob?

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How can I implement a callback (like before_save) on ActiveStorage::Blob?

I try to add the follow to my Initializers folder as blob.rb:

```
require 'active_storage/blob'

class ActiveStorage::Blob
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something

  end
end
```

but getting error while running the server:

> method_missing: undefined method `has_one_attached' for # (NoMethodError)
>   Did you mean?  has_attached_file

Any ideas?
Different approach? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

```
class ActiveStorageBlobObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe "active_storage/blob"

  def after_destroy(blob)
    do_something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class like active_storage_blob_extension.rb in app/models

```
module ActiveStorageBlobExtension

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :do_something

    def do_something
        # do something
    end

  end
end
```

and add it in config/application.rb

```
config.to_prepare do
   ActiveStorage::Blob.send :include, ::ActiveStorageBlobExtension
end
```

the before_save callback will be called before is saved